# What is a "path name component"?

Tags: filesystems, path, terminology, tree, slash

I am not sure I correctly understood what is a *path name component* (or perhaps better written; *path name-component*) which I understand to be commonly abbreviated simply as "component" in the Unix & Linux literature.

> **My understanding so far**
>
> A *directory* file or an *archive* file for that
>   matter are both *aggregated files* ("container files"), which can
>   contain one file or two or more files, in *depth* 1 and possibly in
>   deeper depths as well.
>
> Any possible file (say, an aggregated file
>   or its sub-directory or its sub-archive or even its
>   sub-file of whatever other kind) can have either of these path name-component *kinds*:
>
> - Singular (forwardslash**less**)
> - Plural: Two sub-path-components separated by one forward slash or three or more sub-path-components separated by two or more forward slashes
>
> If a file has a *singular* or *plural*, or not, path name component,
>   is relatively depends on depth.

What is a "path name component"?

Comment: Please slow down and *read* the answers given to questions you’ve already asked.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have read any answer I got so far to best of my ability to understand what I read; not always I understand a particular term so if no one posted a question about it before I gladly do so with explaining what I did manage to understand and probably wrong or inaccurate.

Comment: OK, so since you read it, could you explain what you don’t understand in “Each of these paths has several [components](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_272): `mediawiki-1.33.0/.phan/config.php` has three, `mediawiki-1.33.0`, `.phan`, and `config.php`.”? There’s even a link to the POSIX definition of the term.

Comment: @StephenKitt here I understood you good (I am sure); in the other answer - I got lost with the details early due to some cognitive bias.

Comment: So hopefully you see the point of my request above. By asking new questions like this, you end up leaving a trail of half-answered questions which aren’t particularly useful to anyone else, because they’re intimately tied to your particular misunderstanding of a given point...

Comment: @StephenKitt I kindly disagree; ATMO understanding the fragments of data clearly and conventionally gives broad understanding in the long term; as I have written to luca: Hello, thanks, are you sure it is that easy? I think that the fact that `/path/to/file/` (or a relative `path/to/file/` for that matter) are both a "path name-component" (which is actually, per Stephen's link to POSIX definition a "filename" can be a bit unclear or confusing (at least for me in times of stress).

Comment: But see, that’s a problem too: you explain what you don’t understand, ask for clarification, and when people tell you something that doesn’t match your current understanding, you don’t believe them!

Comment: And I have *absolutely no idea* what you mean by “ATMO understanding the fragments of data clearly and conventionally gives broad understanding in the long term”.

Comment: @StephenKitt it's a coded message. it's means: "start the attack NOW!".

Comment: The question is marked as a duplicate, but the linked answer is actually deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Take the example path `/path/to/file/`. The three components of this path are `path`, `to` and `file`, separated by the delimiting character `/`. It really is as easy as that.

Comment: Hello, thanks, are you sure it is that easy? I think that the fact that `/path/to/file/` (or a relative `path/to/file/` for that matter) are both a "path name-component" (which is actually, per Stephen's link to POSIX definition a "filename" can be a bit unclear or confusing (at least for me in times of stress).

Comment: @JohnDoea I googled it to make sure that I was right  before posting my answer, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) (yes I know it is a bad source but this was enough to convince me) a path component is literally just that. And to explain the filename explanation: Directories are also essentially just files and thus every of the path components is a file name. The only kind of exception are `.`s, since they are not what I would first think of as a filename and can be used in a path but according to Stephen's link they are as well.

Comment: You mean, just a filename? Because I googled "path name" today and got: `A *path name* is a sequence of symbols and names that identifies a file` which now even more feels to me as an awful phrasing that further confused me.

Comment: Also see my edit of the previous comment if that helps but yes, just a file name. Definitions are often hard to grasp since they are quite abstract, but a path name is just a synonym to path aka a unique identifier of the location of a file. Say you have two files named `x`, you need to put them into two different directories or into two different locations in order for them to be reffered to by a unique path. I hope this makes it a bit more clear, but I'll be happy to ask further questions if not.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX defines a [pathname component](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_272) as a filename. The phrase “pathname component” makes sense in the context of a path, *e.g.* `mediawiki-1.33.0/.phan/config.php`, where the components are `mediawiki-1.33.0`, `.phan`, and `config.php`.

I had originally answered this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575336/86440), so this is probably a duplicate.